# Xcode - iOS Simulator window is blank

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I'm running the latest version of macOS Big Sur with Xcode 12.2 beta 3. I build my app for the simulator and it succeeds - but the simulator screen is blank. The same thing happens when I go through the menus and open Simulator manually - `Xcode > Open Developer Tool > Simulator`. I have tried adding a new simulator device, and running `xcode-select --install`.

Preferably, I would rather not have to re-install Xcode as I have limited space and would have to juggle other applications, use an external hard drive etc (I have a 128GB MacBook Air).

[image]

This is what appears when I try both methods.

Comment: go with newly created app or existing ?

Comment: Delete all simulators and start over?

Comment: @matt tried that, didn’t work.

Answer (score 1):

I determined the problem.

There was a bug in the developer beta version I was using.
It was causing the simulator to fail to launch correctly.

I have reported this bug to Apple through Feedback Assistant, and moved to a stable version of Xcode which is now working with the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

I agonised over this for ages since I moved to the MacPro M1.
App run fine on connected fysical IOS device but not in emulator...
Upgrading MacOs and Xcode fixed nothing...
Was finally on MacOS 12.3.1 and Xcode13.3.1 when I figured it out.
The only thing that finally actually worked was removing the check to run Xcode with Rosetta and to be sure downloading a new IOSXXX simulator.
Go to Applications -> right click on Xcode --> Get info --> uncheck Open using Rosetta.
Hope it helps for you!